# Identify $\Gamma (\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q})$. Let $\phi \in \Gamma (\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q})$.

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, field-theory

Use the following plan to identify $\Gamma (\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q})$. Let $\phi \in \Gamma (\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q})$.

1. Prove that $$x>0 \Rightarrow \phi(x)>0$$
2. Prove that $\phi$ is a strictly increasing function.
3. Prove that $\phi(x)=x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

This seems trivial to me, but I don't know where to start on the proof.

Comment: You haven't given us any context in which to figure out what you mean by $\Gamma$.

Comment: What is $\Gamma$ ? Galois group?

Comment: It does seem likely that the question is about galois groups, but that is a guess just from tags.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it is indeed Galois groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Consider the following if $x>0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ then $x=y^2$ with $y\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\phi(x)=\phi(y)^2$ what can you say about the sign of $\phi(x)$?
2. Take $x<y$ then $\phi(y-x)>0$ by $1$, what can you deduce then ?
3. First show that $\phi(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show then that $\phi(z)=z$ for all $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and finally show that $\phi(q)=q$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. Here you just use the fact that $\phi$ is a ring automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $x$ be a real number I can construct two sequences $(q_n^-)$ and $(q_n^+)$ of rational numbers approximating $x$ below and above. This means that :

$$(q_n^-)\text{ is increasing and } q_n^-\rightarrow_n x $$

$$(q_n^+)\text{ is decreasing and } q_n^+\rightarrow_n x $$

So that we have for all $n$ :

$$q_n^-<x<q_n^+ $$

Pass this inequality to $\phi$ (remember that 2 shows that $\phi$ is increasing) then use the fact that $\phi$ fixes any rational number and then conclude.

Comment: Nice. This is a sketch of the well-known theorem that $\Bbb R$ has no automorphisms beyond the identity. Less well known is the same fact for the $p$-adic fields $\Bbb Q_p$.